# How to make boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor block forever?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, blocking

How would someone do that? It just blocks until the first connection attempt.

Comment: Why do you want accept to block forever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::accept` [method](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/accept/overload1.html) already blocks until a connection is attempted.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you can, `accept` will block until the first connection arrives and `async_accept` won't block at all (and will only handle the first connection as well). However, why do you want this? You can always initiate another `accept` once the previous one returned. It's not like you'd miss anything since `accept` only removes theses connections from the listening sockets **queue**.